# can I have one Servername and multiple serveralias in separated conf apache files?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have multiple subdomains.

Ex:

```
www.mysite.com  /var/www/html/mysite.com
it.mysite.com   /var/www/html/it.mysite.com
fr.mysite.com   /var/www/html/fr.mysite.com
```

must I have separated files, how to use the servername and serveralias in every conf file?

Comment: You want to define it in one place, and have it work for every vhost?

Comment: not really, but i'd like to know the two ways, or the best way, because every domain use a diferent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache basically takes all the config files that match the `Include` statements, and combines them into one file. The seperate files are just for management, Apache itself does not care. All combined files are then the configuration. So you can put your configuration files wherever, but you have to point at it with an `Include` statement.

So if you want to make a setting that is global, put it into global (server) context. If you want it to be only valid for a particular vhost, put it into the vhost context. Some settings *have* to have a certain context. You can look these up in the documentation.

`ServerAlias` is only valid in the vhost context, whereas `ServerName` can be both. As such you don't have a choice but need to put `ServerAlias` into each vhost definition.

Comment: I found the supporting documentation for this at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging - "Configurations included via the Include directive will be treated as if they were inside the including file at the location of the Include directive."